# Any reasons I shouldn't calculate the difference between CLR transformed variables to analyze my data in a time-independent way?

Tags: data-transformation, compositional-data

First time posting, so apologies for any missing info and the like.

I have some microbiome data collected from two different treatment groups over two timepoints. I want to look at the compositional changes that occurred between the treatments. To do this, I CLR-transformed my data and I was wondering if there are any reasons I shouldn't take the delta of the CLR-transformed variables.

My math isn't that strong, so I'm not entirely sure how to think about CLR transforms and the resulting delta value obtained from taking the difference.

Any advice is greatly appreciated! Thanks!
Kam